# Match a character followed by another

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I want to find a `.` and get any characters after I found a `(`, with a regex. How do i make that happen?

I would also like to see some good tutorials on regexes for Javascript.

Comment: StackOverflow is not your personal research assistant. What have you tried?

Comment: True, have tried serveral stuff. /\(*?=[.]/g    Dont get it how to obtain more characters then just 1

Comment: Remember that `.` is a special character in a regex. If you want to find one literally, you need to escape it in the regex: `\.` The same goes for `(` when not inside a character class (`[(]` is okay).

Comment: @TedHopp You don't **have** to escape it. You can use `[.]` as the OP is using in their last comment.

Comment: @HerrWalter Look into using the `+` character, which says "Match one or more". So `/[.]+/g` means "Match one or more `.`"

Comment: I'm able to find the '(' and the '.' but not the chars inbetween them, how can I match those?

Comment: Provide some examples of your input string and characters that you want to capture.

Comment: for example "here is a sentance. and some other text ( and i want to get ' and some other text ' "

Comment: `/[.]([^(]*)[(]/` <<< "find a `.`, then any number of characters that are not `(`, then a `(`. Save the characters after the `.` and before the `(` in capture group 1." Note that `()` surrounding `[^(]*` specifies a capture group, which you can access through the regex results.

Comment: @Ian - Right. I worded my comment poorly. Inside `[]` only `^` (when the first character), `-`, `\`, and `]` have special meaning and need to be escaped).

Comment: @TedHopp No problem, just wanted to make sure what was possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following regex should work for you:

```
[.]([^(]*)[(]
```

Text you want to capture will be available in group # 1.

Javascript Code:

```
var str='here is a sentance. and some other text ( here )';
var match = str.match(/[.]([^(]*)[(]/);
console.log(match[1]); //  and some other text
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/ALqusiC9EQ

Comment: Thank you! /[.]([^(]*)[(]/g  is what i actually needed.

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out.

Comment: dafuq why do you use `[.]` and not `\.` http://www.rubular.com/r/G5bp0oOGHp and IMO more clear http://www.rubular.com/r/slbRKxTNeJ

Comment: @acidzombie24: `\.` is really same as `[.]`

Comment: it is but imo looks weird

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're having trouble with the concept of *escaping*. The `.` and `(` characters have special meaning in RegEx, so you need to escape them by placing a `\` in front of them. For example, to match a literal dot, you might use `\.`

For repetition, you can use `*` or `+` for 0+ and 1+ respectively. These are used as *modifiers* on preceding expressions. So, for example, `A+` means "one or more `A` characters", whereas `A*` means "zero or more `A` characters". You can also use the `?` modifier to alter the "greedy" behavior of these matches, but that's a more complicated topic.

If you need to constrain the exact number of repetitions, you can use the `{n}` syntax. For example, you might use `A{10}` to match exactly 10 `A` characters, or `A{3,5}` to match between 3 and 5 `A` characters.

These also work on groups and classes, e.g. `[A-Z]{3}` or `(a*b+){3}`.

As far as RegEx tutorials go, pretty much *nowhere* beats [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), though the [MDN article on RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) might be useful on the JavaScript side of things too.

Comment: Thanks! Great explanation in repetition of collection certain chars. But could you help out on the comments i posted above?

Comment: Dude have I seen you play dota? Bloodseeker seems to be one of your favs

Comment: Me? I've never played DotA in my life. I'm an SC2 fanboy.

Comment: cool. There is a really good player with the name Polynomial who seems to understand programming ;P